# mess with tangents

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line

I have reviewed and drawn this problem several times but I can not see the solution, it must be very simple but I do not see it
Help me please
[image: Figure and its data]

EDIT

[image]

Comment: there is the figure

Comment: Mark with y segments from A and with z segments from $C$

Comment: But, I do not see it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let mark the segments from $A$ with $y$ and from $C$ with $z$. Then we have:

$$ y+x+a =5$$
$$ y+a'+b+a'+z = 8$$
$$ x+a+b+z = 6$$

It is easy to see that $a=a'$: If we extend outer common tangents to say common point $T$ we see that $2a+b +t = 2a'+b+t $, so $a=a'$.

So $$5+6-8 =  (y+x+a)+( x+a+b+z)- (y+a'+b+a'+z) = 2x$$

Comment: ok ,  why do you subtract that 8, no...I already saw it

Comment: it is correct to put "a" and "a" to the outer tangents to the left to the middle, to the right below, I doubt that

Comment: I agree with @juan muñoz There is no apparent reason that the segments at the bottom have same lengths $a$ and $a$ as the other two segments $a$ and $a$ in the middle... Besides, how is defined line BL: I don't think it is a median... neither an angle bissector... For the circles no problem once line BL is defined...

Comment: then it could not be calculated like this, because I get to 2x + 2 (a + a ') = 3

Comment: I will see it calmly, thank you, thank you very much

Comment: You could explain this step in the drawing

It is easy to see that a=a′: If we extend outer common tangents to say common point T we see that 2a+b+t=2a′+b+t, so a=a′.